# Вызов окна из другого класса в Java

Tags: java, ооп

Есть окно JFrame (класс create) на котором размещена кнопочка. Есть второй класс choose, который состоит из другого окна JFrame. Как сделать так, чтоб при запуске класса create, и нажатии на кнопку открывалось второе окно JFrame из класса choose?

```
public class create_frame {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

    // Main Frame
    JFrame frame=new JFrame("Sanctuary :: Welcome");
    frame.setLayout(null);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(830, 640));
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //TERMS
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

//Новая игра
        bt1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {   
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                bt1.getAction(choose_char.);
            }
        });
```

и

```
public class choose_char extends create_frame {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    final JFrame chch = new JFrame("Создание персонажа");
    chch.setLayout(null);
    chch.setSize(new Dimension(1000, 800));
    chch.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); //TERMS
    chch.setVisible(true);
    chch.setResizable(false);
    chch.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    chch.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

}
```

}

Comment: Классы обычно пишутся с большой буквы и без нижних подчеркиваний. Соблюдайте Java Code Convention и другим программистам будет проще понять ваш код.

Answer (score 1):

Перенесите код из метода `main` в конструктор и обработчике события нажатия на кнопку создавайте новый объект класса.

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с предыдущим ответом - замени метод `main` на конструктор(`create_frame()`), и в обработчике создай анонимный объект - `new choose_char();` должно сработать